# extract a string in java

Tags: java, string

I have a string like bellow

```
String s = "A<>B<>C<>D<>"
```

and A,B,C,D are unknown 
I want to separate "C" 
According to this information that it is between the second and third "<>" how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String[] parts = s.split("<>");
String wanted = parts[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `split`:

```
int first = s.indexOf("<>");
int second = s.indexOf("<>", first + 2);
int third = s.indexOf("<>", second + 2);

String wanted = s.substring(second + 2, third);
```

Comment: thanks , I have a question about this method ,  why did you add +2 ?

Comment: Try it without the +2.